# PHP calendar class Ajax Calendar control, Date switch on dec to jan and back to dec again

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, date, calendar

Okay so here's the deal I've made a PHP calendar class as seen here http://pastebin.com/QERgmn8y also I've got an ajax script that will switch calendar dates and years if certain conditions are met as seen here http://pastebin.com/kfrmz79J

and since I don't have enough repotation just yet here is the ID to the final script on PasteBin the id is **JKdi6H8f** this script makes it all happen

now so far I've tried multiple conditions such as

```
if(prevMon > mon ){//set year to -1};
```

and

`if(nextMon < mon){//set year to +1};`

and many other conditions but those seemed to work the best so far the only problem is that, when I switch dates to december and then go back it goes up a year, or if I get to december then switch to january and back to december the year will remain 2014 instead of going back one.

if anyone can find a solution to this problem I'd be greatful.

also here are the snippets of relevant code

```
 //next month is clicked
        $(document).on('click',"#next_month", function(){
                var selected =$(this).attr('class');
                date.setMonth(selected-1);
                var mon = date.getMonth();
                var prevMon = date.getMonth()-1;
                if(prevMon < 0){
                        prevMon = 11;
                }
                var nextMon = date.getMonth()+1;
                if(nextMon > 11){
                        nextMon = 0;
                }
                var remain = 11 - mon;
                var currY = date.getFullYear();
                console.log(selected+"current m: "+mon+" prev m: "+prevMon+" next m: "+nextMon+" current y: "+currY+" remainder: "+remain);

                if(remain == 0){
                        date.setFullYear(currY+1);
                        console.log(currY);
                }
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "calendar/calendar.php",
                        data: {nMonth: selected, year: currY},
                        success: function(data){
                                var d = data.split("▼");
                                $("#cal_wrap").html(d[1]);
                                $("#cal_header_wrap").html(d[0]);
                        }
                });
        });

        //previous month is clicked
        $(document).on('click',"#prev_month", function(){
                var selected =$(this).attr('class');
                date.setMonth(selected-1);
                var mon = date.getMonth();
                var prevMon = date.getMonth()+1;
                if(prevMon > 11){
                        prevMon = 0;
                }
                var nextMon = date.getMonth()-1;
                if(nextMon < 0){
                        nextMon = 11;
                }
                var remain = 11 - mon;
                var currY = date.getFullYear();
                console.log(selected+"current m: "+mon+" prev m: "+prevMon+" next m: "+nextMon+" current y: "+currY+" remainder: "+remain);

                if(remain == 11){
                        date.setFullYear(currY-1);
                        console.log(currY);
                }
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "calendar/calendar.php",
                        data: {pMonth: selected, year: currY},
                        success: function(data){
                                var d = data.split("▼");
                                $("#cal_wrap").html(d[1]);
                                $("#cal_header_wrap").html(d[0]);
                        }
                });
        });
```

and the PHP script

```
if(isset($nMonth)){
                //sets the year to what javascript returns
                $cal->setY($year);
                $nm = mktime(0,0,0,$nMonth,1,$cal->getY(),0);
                $month = date("m",$nm);
                $cal->setM($month);
                $cal->showCalHeader();
                echo "▼";
                $cal->showWeek();
                $cal->showCalendar();
        }else if(isset($pMonth)){
                //sets the year to what javascript returns
                $cal->setY($year);
                //sets the month to previous month
                $pm = mktime(0,0,0,$pMonth,1,2013,0);
                $month = date("m",$pm);
                $cal->setM($month);
                $cal->showCalHeader();
                echo "▼";
                $cal->showWeek();
                $cal->showCalendar();  
        }
```

Comment: Iy would be better if you could post samples of your code within your question

Comment: the code in question is too long so I used pastebin, but sure I'll add the relevant snippets